# How to query for inner_hits against grandparents in multi-generational setup

Tags: elasticsearch

So I've set up my Elasticsearch store according to this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/grandparents.html

```
PUT /company
{
  "mappings": {
    "country": {},
    "branch": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "country" 
      }
    },
    "employee": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "branch" 
      }
    }
  }
}
POST /company/country/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": "uk" }}
{ "name": "UK" }
{ "index": { "_id": "france" }}
{ "name": "France" }

POST /company/branch/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": "london", "parent": "uk" }}
{ "name": "London Westmintster" }
{ "index": { "_id": "liverpool", "parent": "uk" }}
{ "name": "Liverpool Central" }
{ "index": { "_id": "paris", "parent": "france" }}
{ "name": "Champs Élysées" }

PUT /company/employee/1?parent=london&routing=uk 
{
  "name":  "Alice Smith",
  "dob":   "1970-10-24",
  "hobby": "hiking"
}
```

This query works fine and returns Alice as expected, but no inner_hits:

```
POST /company/employee/_search
{
    "query": {
        "has_parent": {
            "type": "branch",
            "query": {
                "term": {"_id": "london"}
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
        }
    }
}
```

But this query doesn't return any inner_hits:

```
POST /company/employee/_search
{
    "query": {
        "has_parent": {
            "type": "branch",
            "query": {
                "has_parent": {
                    "type": "country",
                    "query": {
                        "term": {"_id": "uk"}
                    }
                },
                "inner_hits": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it would return Alice, but it doesn't. How do I find all employees whose country is `uk`?

Note that the example query on elastic.co doesn't return any inner_hits either. Here's the query:

```
GET /company/country/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "branch",
      "query": {
        "has_child": {
          "type": "employee",
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "hobby": "hiking"
            }
          },
          "inner_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got zero inner_hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently an outstanding with `inner_hits`.

You can add on the issue here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11118